# How to save image to device from cache

Tags: android, bitmap, save

Why can't I save the Drawing Cache in the device storage

```
else if(view.getId()==R.id.save_btn){
        //save drawing
        AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        saveDialog.setTitle("Save drawing");

        saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to device Gallery?");

        saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
```

The save detail

```
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                //save drawing
                drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
```

if the image saved

```
                if(imgSaved!=null){
                    Toast savedToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Drawing saved to Gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    savedToast.show();
                }
```

If the image not saved

```
             else {
                    Toast unsavedToast = Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Oops! Image could not be saved.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            unsavedToast.show();
                        }
```

The Error logcat
[image]

Comment: What is happening?  Are you receiving an error?  Or?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Please edit your post and tell us what you are observing.  What is your code doing wrong ?

Comment: i am receiving some error i have capture for the error when i save the cache
the error is uploaded on the top